# I wanted to perform crud operations for Admin Panel of an ecommerce project but not able to edit image gallery in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, crud

ProductModel  class file

```
    public class ProductModel 
    {
            public int ProductID { get; set; }
            
            public string ProductName { get; set; }
            public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
            public string Image { get; set; }
            
            public IFormFile Img { get; set; }
            public IFormFileCollection GalleryImages { get; set; }
            public List<ProductGalleryModel> ProductGallery { get;set;}
    }
```

ProductGalleryModel class file

```
public class ProductGalleryModel
            {
                public int ID { get; set; }
                public int ProductId { get; set; }
                public string  Name { get; set; }
                public string URL { get; set; }
                public IFormFileCollection GalleryImages { get; set; }
        
                public List<ProductGalleryModel> ProductGallery { get; set; }
        
            }
```

ProductController class file

```
public class ProductController : Controller
            {
         private readonly IProductRepository _productRepository = null;
        
        public ProductController(IProductRepository productRepository)
                {
                    _productRepository = productRepository;
        
                }
        
         public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewProduct(bool isSuccess = false, int prodId = 0)
                {
                    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategories(), "CatID", "CategoryName");
                    ViewBag.IsSuccess = isSuccess;
                    ViewBag.ProductID = prodId;
                    return View();
                }
        
        [HttpPost]
                public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewProduct(ProductModel productModel)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        if (productModel.Img1 != null)
                        {
                            string folder = "images/product/cover/";
                            productModel.Image1 = await UploadImage(folder, productModel.Img1);
                        }
                        if (productModel.GalleryImages != null)
                        {
                            string folder = "images/product/cover/gallery/";
        
                            productModel.ProductGallery = new List<ProductGalleryModel>();
        
                            foreach (var file in productModel.GalleryImages)
                            {
                                var gallery = new ProductGalleryModel() 
                                {
                                        Name = file.FileName,
                                        URL = await UploadImage(folder, file)
                                  };
                                productModel.ProductGallery.Add(gallery);
                            }
        
                        }
        
                        var id = await _productRepository.AddProduct(productModel);
                        if (id > 0)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction(nameof(AddNewProduct), new { isSuccess = true, prodId = id });
                        }
                    }
        
                    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategories(), "CatID", "CategoryName");
                    return View();
                }
        
        private async Task<string> UploadImage(string folderPath, IFormFile file)
                {
                    folderPath += Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + file.FileName;
                    string serverfolderpath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, folderPath);
                    await file.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(serverfolderpath, FileMode.Create));
                    return "/" + folderPath;
                }
        
         public async Task<IActionResult> GetProductGallery(int id)
                {
                    var data = await _productRepository.GetProductById(id);
                    return View(data);
                }
        
                public async Task<IActionResult> EditProductGallery (int id, bool isSuccess = false)
                {
                    ViewBag.IsSuccess = isSuccess;
                    ViewBag.ProductID = id;
        
                    var ListOfProducts = await _productRepository.GetProductById(id);
                    ViewData["ProductGallery"] = ListOfProducts.ProductGallery;
                    return View(ListOfProducts);
                }
         public async Task<PartialViewResult> RenderProduct(int id)
                {
                    var ListOfProducts = await _productRepository.GetProductById(id);
                   ViewData["ProductGallery"] = ListOfProducts.ProductGallery;
                    return PartialView(ListOfProducts);
                }
        
                public async Task<PartialViewResult> RenderProductGallery(int id)
                {
                    var ListOfProducts = await _productRepository.getProductGallery(id);
                    ViewData["ProductId"] = ListOfProducts.ProductGallery;
                    return PartialView(ListOfProducts);
                }
        
         [HttpPost]
                public async Task<IActionResult> EditProductGallery(ProductGalleryModel productGalleryModel)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        if (productGalleryModel.URL != null)
                        {
                            if (productGalleryModel.GalleryImages != null)
                            {
                                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(productGalleryModel.GalleryImages.ToString());
                                string filePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, fileName);
                                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        
                                string folder = "images/product/cover/gallery/";
                                productGalleryModel.ProductGallery = new List<ProductGalleryModel>();
        
                                foreach (var file in productGalleryModel.GalleryImages)
                                {
                                    var gallery = new ProductGalleryModel()
                                    {
                                        Name = file.FileName,
                                        URL = await UploadImage(folder, file)
                                    };
        
                                   
                                    productGalleryModel.ProductGallery.Add(gallery);
                                }
                                await _productRepository.UpdateProductGallery(productGalleryModel.ID, productGalleryModel);
                            }
                        }
                        
                        return RedirectToAction("GetAllProducts", new { isSuccess = true, ViewBag.ProductID });
                    }
                    return View();
                }
        
         
        }
        
        }
```

ProductRepository for all get and edit methods

```
public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
            {
             public async Task<ProductGalleryModel> getProductGallery(int id)
                {
                    var result = await _prcContext.tblProductGalleries.Where(x => x.ProductsProductID == id).
                    Select(getgallerybyid => new ProductGalleryModel()
                    {
                        URL = getgallerybyid.URL,
                    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                    
                    return result;   
                }
        
          public async Task<ProductModel> GetProductById(int id)
                {
                    return await _prcContext.tblProducts.Where(x => x.ProductID == id).
                        Select(getproductbyId => new ProductModel()
                        {
                            ProductID = getproductbyId.ProductID,
                            ProductName = getproductbyId.ProductName,
                            ProductDesc = getproductbyId.ProductDesc,
                            Image1 = getproductbyId.Image1,
                            Image2 = getproductbyId.Image2,
                            Image3 = getproductbyId.Image3,
                            Image4 = getproductbyId.Image4,
                            OldPrice = getproductbyId.OldPrice,
                            NewPrice = getproductbyId.NewPrice,
                            Discount = getproductbyId.Discount,
                            CategoryId = getproductbyId.CategoryId,
                            ProductGallery = getproductbyId.productGallery.Select(g => new ProductGalleryModel()
                            { 
                                    ID = g.GalleryID,
                                    ProductId = g.ProductsProductID,
                                    Name = g.Name,
                                    URL= g.URL
                            }).ToList()
                        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        
              }
        
        public async Task<ProductModel> UpdateProduct(int id, ProductModel productModel)
                {
                    var updateProduct = await _prcContext.tblProducts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProductID == id);
                    if (updateProduct != null)
                    {
                        updateProduct.ProductName = productModel.ProductName;
                        updateProduct.ProductDesc = productModel.ProductDesc;
                        updateProduct.Image1 = productModel.Image1;
                        updateProduct.Image2 = productModel.Image2;
                        updateProduct.Image3 = productModel.Image3;
                        updateProduct.Image4 = productModel.Image4;
                        updateProduct.OldPrice = productModel.OldPrice;
                        updateProduct.NewPrice = productModel.NewPrice;
                        updateProduct.Discount = productModel.Discount;
                        updateProduct.CategoryId = productModel.CategoryId;
                    }
                    await _prcContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return productModel;
                }
                public async Task<ProductGalleryModel> UpdateProductGallery(int id, ProductGalleryModel productGalleryModel)
                {
        
                    var updateProductGallery = await _prcContext.tblProductGalleries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProductsProductID == id);
                    if (updateProductGallery != null)
                    {
                        var newproduct = new List<tblProductGallery>();
        
                        foreach (var gallery in newproduct)
                        {
                            updateProductGallery.URL = productGalleryModel.URL;
                        }
                        await _prcContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    
                    return productGalleryModel;
                }
        
        }
```

Edit Product Gallery View file

```
 @model ProductGalleryModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Product Gallery";
        Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <style>
        .img-fluid {
            width: 250px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row mb-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Edit Product Gallery</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb float-md-right">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a asp-action="GetAllProducts" asp-controller="Product">Products</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Edit Product Gallery</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </section>
        <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
    
                <div class="card card-primary py-2">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Existing Gallery</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
    
                        <div class="row">
                            <input type="hidden" value="@ViewData["ProductGallery"]" />
                            <partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/RenderProduct.cshtml"
                                     view-data="ViewData" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title">Update Gallery</h3>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="EditProductGallery" asp-controller="Product">
                        <div class="card-body">
    
                            <div class="row">
                                <partial name="~/Areas/Admin/Views/RenderProductGallery.cshtml" view-data="ViewData" />
                                <div class="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    
    @section Scripts
    {
        <script>
            
            $(document).ready(function () {
    
                $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                    var filename = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(filename);
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Product PartialView

```
    @model ProductModel
    
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <img src="@Model.Image1" class="img-fluid mb-2" alt="white sample" />
        </div>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductGallery.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <img src="@Model.ProductGallery[i].URL" class="img-fluid mb-2" alt="white sample" />
            </div>
        }
```

Product Gallery PartialView

```
    model ProductGalleryModel
    @{
        ViewData["ProductGallery"] = true;
    }
    
    <div class="">
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.ProductId" />
        @*<input type="hidden" value="@Model.ProductGallery" />*@
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="GalleryImages"></label>
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input asp-for="GalleryImages" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="GalleryImages" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section Scripts
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
    
                $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                    var filename = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(filename);
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

I am able to return the ProductPartialView with desired results but when i am calling the ProductGalleryPartialView then i am getting an Exception: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'PRC_webapp.Areas.Admin.Models.ProductModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'PRC_webapp.Areas.Admin.Models.ProductGalleryModel'.

Comment: your code is not formatted properly and it is hard to copy and paste to reproduce. also it is not clear what the problem is... are you getting an error? what exactly is "not working"?

Comment: I apologize for my wrong formation, yes Jonathan, I am getting an exception when i am performing edit operation with ProductGallery Model. In the above Code, Product Model and ProductGallery Model share relation as ProductModel >> FK to ProductGalleryModel. I am storing images of ProductGallery in a different table with reference to ProductModel as foreign-key. The exception that raised is given in the question, as i am short of characters for commenting. Please, need help in this situation or i am also ready to change the above code from model-to-Controller-to-View  as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(_context.students);
}
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(student student)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
 
    student.Image = await student.Photo.SaveFileAsync(_env.WebRootPath, "images");
    await _context.students.AddAsync(student);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var student = await _context.students.FindAsync(id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return View(student);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int? id, student newstudent)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var oldstudent = _context.students.Find(id);
    if (oldstudent == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    var path = Helper.GetPath(_env.WebRootPath, "img", oldstudent.Image);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }
    newstudent.Image = await newstudent.Photo.SaveFileAsync(_environment.WebRootPath, "images");
    oldstudent.Image = newstudent.Image;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var student = _context.students.Find(id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    var path = Helper.GetPath(_environment.WebRootPath, "img", student.Image);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
    }
    _context.students.Remove(student);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).